# Mysql High Load Average

Tags: mysql

my server is getting a very high load average because of the mysql daemon, sometimes up to over 100.0. First i thought that its because of mysql slow querys, here is one snippet from the mysql-slow.log:

```
# Time: 150423

  6:38:03
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 1.349115  Lock_time: 0.000181 Rows_sent: 40  Rows_examined: 16552
SET timestamp=1429763883;
SELECT * FROM videos, videos_tags WHERE videos.Id = videos_tags.Id AND videos.ImporterTag=0  AND Published IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Published DESC LIMIT 0,40; 
# Time: 150423  6:38:36
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 2.110382  Lock_time: 0.000107 Rows_sent: 40  Rows_examined: 18517
use db;
SET timestamp=1429763916;
SELECT * FROM videos, videos_tags WHERE videos.Id = videos_tags.Id AND videos.ImporterTag=0  AND Published IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Published DESC LIMIT 1080,40;
# Time: 150423  6:39:26
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 1.855701  Lock_time: 0.000075 Rows_sent: 200  Rows_examined: 19316
use db;
SET timestamp=1429763966;
SELECT * FROM videos, videos_tags WHERE videos.Id = videos_tags.Id AND videos.ImporterTag=0  AND Published IS NOT NULL ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,200;
```

After that i got some messages that tables are marked as 'crashed'. I repaired them using mysqlcheck und myisamchk, until now it seems to run fine.

Can anybody tell me if the querys look like slow querys? if not, the failure should be because of the crashed databases.

Comment: 2 seconds to examine 18000 rows seems slow to me. you need to `explain` those queries and see if you can improve their index usage

Comment: I really hope you're not using MyISAM to store important data. Secondly, you need to tune your database properly. This is a question better answered on the [DBA site](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: try doing a join, that should reduce the rows examined and let us know the results